# A shorter & nicer Ruby style way of writing this #valid_rook_moves method, or an alternative algorithm?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a method that will output the valid moves that a Rook chess piece could legally make (without consideration of any other pieces on the board). A working method that I've written is below. It has access to readable (and writable, thus the `.dup`) `@x` and `@y` variables whose values are the rook piece's location on an 8x8 grid  chess board in zero indexed format coordinates. But it's a pretty verbose and ugly method i think, can anyone offer a) a nicer syntactic way to write the below, or b) a nice alternative way of achieving the desired output.

```
def valid_rook_moves
    moves = []
    new_x = x.dup
    until new_x >= 7
      new_x += 1
      moves.push([new_x, y])
    end
    
    new_x = x.dup
    until new_x <= 0
      new_x -= 1
      moves.push([new_x, y])
    end
    
    new_y = y.dup
    until new_y >= 7
      new_y += 1
      moves.push([x, new_y]) 
    end
    
    new_y = y.dup
    until new_y <= 0
      new_y -= 1
      moves.push([x, new_y]) 
    end
    
    moves
  end
```

For example running this method with @x and @y both being set to 0 outputs:

```
[[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], [7, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
```

Comment: `x` and `y` are not defined in your method. Did you forget to use `@`'s in your code?

Comment: @x and @y instance variables have reader and writer methods written for them, so this #valid_rook_moves instance method can call the #x and #y reader methods that read the @x and @y instance variables.

Comment: Then you need to include that info in the question itself. As given, this is not a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Ugly and nice are opinion based concepts.  The whole question might be more appropriate on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `moves = (0..7).zip([x]*8) + ([y]*8).zip(0..7) - [[x ,y]]` is definitely shorter.

Comment: @pjs I did include that info in the question itself, see the 3rd sentence that I wrote.

Comment: Ha ha, yup @steenslag your zip approach is definitely shorter! Thank you.

Comment: @jbk You did put that verbiage in, but the code is not an MRE as written. If somebody copies and pastes the code you provided, it will not run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way...

```
VEC = (0..7).to_a.freeze
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

```
def valid_rook_moves(x, y)
  ([x].product(VEC)).concat(VEC.product([y]))- [[x,y]]
end
```

```
valid_rook_moves(0, 0)
  #=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7],
  #    [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], [7, 0]]
```

```
valid_rook_moves(3, 5)
  #=> [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 6], [3, 7],
  #    [0, 5], [1, 5], [2, 5], [4, 5], [5, 5], [6, 5], [7, 5]]
```

See [Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-new), [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product) and [Array#concat](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-concat).

Note that for `x = 3` and `y = 5`,

```
[x].product(VEC)
  #=> [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7]]
```

```
VEC.product([y])
  #=> [[0, 5], [1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5], [5, 5], [6, 5], [7, 5]]
```

---

And another...

```
def valid_rook_moves(x, y)
  (0..7).each_with_object([]) do |i,a|
    a << [x,i] unless i == y
    a << [i,y] unless i == x
  end
end
```

```
valid_rook_moves(0, 0)
  #=> [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [2, 0], [0, 3], [3, 0], [0, 4],
  #    [4, 0], [0, 5], [5, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [0, 7], [7, 0]]
```

```
valid_rook_moves(3, 5)
  #=> [[3, 0], [0, 5], [3, 1], [1, 5], [3, 2], [2, 5], [3, 3],
  #    [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 5], [3, 6], [6, 5], [3, 7], [7, 5]]
```

Comment: I hadn't spotted Array#product before, nice!

Comment: Or less obscure with `VEC = (0..7).to_a.freeze`.

Comment: @HolgerJust, you're right. I yielded to my fondness for `Array::new`. Could of course also write `VEC = [*0..7].freeze`.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```ruby
def range_excluding(value)
  [*0...value, *(value+1)...8]
end

def valid_rook_moves(current_x, current_y)
  ([current_x] * 7).zip(range_excluding(current_y)) +
    range_excluding(current_x).zip([current_y] * 7)
end

p valid_rook_moves(0, 0)
p valid_rook_moves(3, 5)
```

One benefit of passing a position using method arguments rather than using the current position is that it gives flexibility to consider a sequence of future moves rather than restricting you to only the next move.